# Перевод из секунд в часы:минуты

Tags: java, android, время

Есть переменная time, в ней хранятся секунды, которые нужно перевести в формат HH:mm. Проблема в том, что при использовании SimpleDateFormat или ручным переводом выходит результат 00:00, даже если прошло 10 минут. Хелп плиз.

С данным примером кода выводит только секунды. (прошла 1 минута 3 секунды, выводит "00:03" заместо "01:03")

```
  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss") ;
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    result= format.format(new Date(time*1000));
```

Comment: Покажите код...

Comment: Попробуйте сбросить тайм-зону у форматтера `format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Comment: @katso Добавила код.

Comment: @AlexChermenin не помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static String timeToString(long secs) {
        long hour = secs / 3600,
                min = secs / 60 % 60,
                sec = secs / 1 % 60;
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec);
    }
```

Вывод

```
System.out.println(timeToString(63));
```

> 0:01:03

Comment: спустя 1 мин 7 сек выдало 0:00:07 :((

Comment: Вы уверенны что там было число 67(т.е. 1 мин и 7 сек)? `System.out.println("Secs:" + time + ". Formatted: " + timeToString(time));`

Comment: Судя по всему у вас ваша переменная обнуляется по истечению минуты(т.е. спустя 60 сек снова становится = 0)

Comment: Да, точно. Но я уже решила проблему, помог только перевод в миллисекунды и из них в формат.

Comment: Не совсем понял как это с обнулением связанно, но хорошо что получилось. Поздравляю!